# Prove $ \{(p \lor q) \land (p \implies r) \land (q \implies r) \} \implies r$ is a tautology using logical properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

I spent quite a bit of time on this and have little to no ideas on how to proceed.

Using the conditional laws and De Morgan's law, I got to
$$( \sim p \land \sim q) \lor (p \land  \sim r) \lor(q \land \sim r) \lor r$$.

Comment: To show that it is a tautology, take the negation of your statement and check that it leads to a contradiction/is unsatisfiable.

Comment: A strategy I used with these problems was to reduce everything into elementary operations (AND, OR, NEGATION) and go from there. The logical implication can be simplified using it's definition $p \implies q \equiv p \rightarrow q \wedge q \rightarrow p$. Implication can further be reduced using the rule I know as "Implication Reduction" which states: $p \right arrow q \equiv \neg p \vel q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the path is clearer if you leave the $\neg(p\vee q)$ as is when you use de Morgan's Law on everything else.

$\begin{array}{l|ll}
1: & \big((p\vee q)\wedge (p\to r)\wedge (q\to r) \big) \to r 
\\ & \Updownarrow \text{Implication equivalence, thrice}
\\ 2: & \neg\big((p\vee q)\wedge (\neg p\vee r)\wedge (\neg q\vee r) \big) \vee r 
\\ & \Updownarrow \text{de Morgan's Negations}
\\ 3: & \neg (p\vee q)\vee (p\wedge \neg r)\vee (q\wedge\neg r) \vee r 
\\ & \Updownarrow \vee \text{ Idempotent Introduction, Commutivity}
\\ 4: & \neg (p\vee q)\vee (p\wedge \neg r)\vee r\vee (q\wedge\neg r) \vee r 
\\  & \Updownarrow \text{Distribution, Complementation, }\wedge\text{ Identity: } (a\wedge\neg b)\vee b= a\vee b  
\\ 5: & \neg (p\vee q)\vee (p\vee r)\vee (q\vee r) 
\\  & \Updownarrow \text{Association, Commutation, }\vee\text{ Idempotence }
\\ 6: & \neg (p\vee q)\vee (p\vee q) \vee r 
\\  & \Updownarrow \text{Complementation: } A\vee \neg A=\top
\\ 7: & \top \vee r 
\\  & \Updownarrow \vee \text{ Annihlation: } \top\vee r=\top
\\ 8: & \top 
\end{array}$

Comment: It's one thing to drop parentheses and use abbreviations.  It is entirely another to claim *to have proved* a *tautology* when there exist more than one possible tautology which the string of characters represents.

Comment: There appears to be an error in step 6; there is not the same thing inside the parentheses $(p \wedge q)$ and $(p \vee q)$ so you cannot use complementation.

Comment: It was the ∧ Identity and the ∨ Idempotent Introduction that helped me solve it. I will keep it in mind in the future, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Laws used,
$$a\implies b=\overline a\lor b$$
$$a\lor (b\land c)=(a\lor b)\land (a\lor c)$$
$$a\lor \overline a=1$$
$$1\lor a=1$$
$$
\overline{(p\lor q)\land (\overline p\lor r)\land (\overline q\lor r)}\lor r
$$
$$
=\overline{(p\lor q)}\lor \overline {(\overline p\lor r)}\lor \overline {(\overline q\lor r)}\lor r
$$
$$
=(\overline p\land \overline q)\lor (p \land \overline q)\lor (q\land \overline r)\lor r
$$
$$
=(\overline q\land (\overline p\lor p)) \lor (q\land \overline r)\lor r
$$
$$
=\overline q\lor (q\land \overline r)\lor r
$$
$$
=((\overline q\lor q)\land (\overline q\lor \overline r))\lor r
$$
$$
=\overline q\lor \overline r\lor r
$$
$$
=\overline q\lor 1
$$
$$
=1
$$

Comment: It's one thing to drop parentheses and use abbreviations.  It is entirely another to claim *to have proved* a *tautology* when there exist more than one possible tautology which the string of characters represents.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from where you correctly arrived, namely

$$( \sim p \land \sim q) \lor (p \land  \sim r) \lor(q \land \sim r) \lor r,\tag{1}$$

one can expand it using the distributive law into a conjunction of eight terms of the form $a \lor b \lor c \lor d,$ where in each case $d=r,$ while $a,b,c$ are each obtained by choosing one of the two terms in the first, second, or third parentheses of $(1).$ For example one of these terms is $\sim p \lor \sim r \lor q \lor r.$ If one can use the commutative and associative laws, and the two laws $x \lor \sim x=1$ and $y \lor 1 =1,$ then each of the eight terms in the conjunction can be shown to be $1$ since each contains at least one case of the type $x \lor \sim x$ (once they are moved next to each other). So after this application of the distributive law, your formula becomes the conjunction of eight terms which are all provably $1$, and the result is the conjunction of $1$'s so winds up as $1$ meaning it's a tautology.

Comment: Does this advice hold for proofs of *both* tautologies which come as possible from the string of characters given?  I guess it does, but you've still said that he has a formula here.  The author has not given us a formula, and thus the string of chracters can't get proven as a tautology as you have suggested.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I started out in what I called $(1)$ here, which is an equivalent version of what the OP wanted to show is a tautology. I don't see here any more than one tautology, and to me the author *has* given us a formula, namely $(1)$ which is as I say equivalent to the original desired formula to be shown a tautology. It (the "string of characters" has some obvious parsings into versions technically using only binary $\lor$'s, which are all equivalent anyway using the usual laws of basic logic. To me these aren't essentially different, because of their equivalence with each other.

Comment: "To me these aren't essentially different, because of their equivalence with each other."  This line of reasoning would make all tautologies not essentially different because of their equivalence with each other.  I can barely express how absurd such an idea is.  At the very least, it can't get maintained in an axiomatic framework with a fixed rule of inference such as condensed detachment, since for two formulas A, B, formula A cannot get used to derive the same formulas as formula B in general.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Are you saying that e.g one needs to show $(p \land (q \land r)) \implies p$ separately from showing $(p \land (q \land r)) \implies p$ because in one of them the ands are grouped differently? If so to me the use of something as simple as the associative law for $\land$ to show a tautology is really OK. Of course all tautologies are equivalent, and the main purpose of the task to show one holds is to use laws already known so as to reduce it to $1$ (or T).

Comment: I am saying that you need to show [((p∧q)∧r) ⟹p] separately from [(p∧(q∧r)) ⟹p] (this isn't what you wrote, but I believe you meant that).  They are distinct as tautologies.  I am also saying that is not clear which tautology $ \{(p \lor q) \land (p \implies r) \land (q \implies r) \} \implies r$  refers to.

Comment: Right about my typo, I meant to give examples of two obvious tautologies only differing via the associative law applied  inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Wiki definition --

[A formula of propositional logic is a tautology if the formula itself is always true regardless of which valuation is used for the propositional variables.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) --

Here is another challenging solution: The truth table:

[image]

Comment: Did you not answer my geometry question with pictures, and erase it?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: Yes, but I undelete it already.

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align}
(p\land\lnot r)\lor(q\land\lnot r)\lor r\equiv ((p\lor q)\land\lnot r)\lor r\equiv p\lor q \\
(\lnot p\land \lnot q)\lor(p\land\lnot r)\lor(q\land\lnot r)\lor r\equiv (\lnot p\land\lnot q)\lor (p\lor q) \equiv (\lnot p\land \lnot q) \lor p \lor q\equiv \top
\end{align}

Comment: It's one thing to drop parentheses and use abbreviations.  It is entirely another to claim *to have proved* a *tautology* when there exist more than one possible tautology which the string of characters represents.

Answer (score -2):

At this point in time you can't prove this as a tautology.  Tautologies get defined as well-formed formulas.  It is not clear if you mean the tautology (in Polish or Lukasiewicz notation)

C(K(K(A(p,q),C(p,r)),C(q,r)),r).

or if you mean the tautology

C(K(A(p,q),K(C(p,r),C(q,r))),r).

The *proofs* of those well-formed formulas are distinct.

Comment: Based on the Wiki definition --
[A formula of propositional logic is a tautology if the formula itself is always true regardless of which valuation is used for the propositional variables.][2][2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)

Comment: Except that logical and is associative... I don't think your answer is very clear.

Comment: @zoli Check the definition of formula in the hyperlinked wiki by the term 'formula'.  In the form specified by that wiki, what is the formula referred to by (p∨q)∧(p→r)∧(q→r)]→r?

Comment: There are two ways to group the ands on the left side, which are equivalent via the associative law. For an associative operation * like $\land$ it's really no mistake to extend to length more than two, since $a*b*c$ no matter how the parentheses are inserted, is the same via the associativity of $*$.

Comment: Suppose our only axiom is CKpqp and the only rule of inference is condensed detachment.  In that system from KKpqr as an assumption we can infer Kpq.  But from KpKqr as an assumption we cannot infer Kpq.

KKpqr and KpKqr are semantically equivalent, yes.  They are by no means syntactically equivalent, and it's not just a matter of relabeling them according to the grammar.  They actually behave differently in the presence of other formulas.